# Should a traditional while loop like this change to streams in Java and how?

Tags: java, stream

Should I focus on trying to change every loop in my project to new Streams ? Should the loop below change to streams and how?

```
while(characterAfterEncryption > 122) {
                    characterAfterEncryption -= 26; 
                }
```

Trying to avoid using Traditional loops in Java 8.

Unable to find a way how to do it using Streams?

Comment: Sorry, but the snippet of code you've shared doesn't make much sense even without streams. If you want to use streams but don't know where to start - then start with **learning** basic information about [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html). And one of the very first thing you need to remember is that streams are **not** a just another way of writing loop, and they are not applicable in every case where loops can be used.

Comment: I want characterAfterEncryption in range 97 to 122 and until it is not I am subtracting  26 in each iteration from it.

Comment: Did you manage to read so quickly the information provided via links in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359957/should-a-traditional-while-loop-like-this-change-to-streams-in-java-and-how?noredirect=1#comment131274895_74359957) ?

Comment: Why are you using a loop rather than n' = n - (n-97)/26 * 26 (all integer operations)?

Comment: *Should I focus on trying to change every loop in my project to new Streams?* In a word, **No**.

Answer (score 1):

Use streams if and only if the stream-based code is easier to understand than the loop-based code. Streams and loops are both valid Java constructs, and it's the developer's responsibility to decide which one to use.

Streams are designed to support cases where you want to operate on multiple input values, e.g. from lists or sets or other series of data. And this does not apply to your snippet: you have a single input value. So, while it might be possible to create some piece of code that replicates the iterative algorithm using the streams API, the result will surely be very hard to read.

So, forget about "Trying to avoid using Traditional loops in Java 8". There are cases where this is a good idea, but also cases where the traditional loop is exactly the right thing to do. And if you ever tried to debug a streams expression, you'll be even more hesitant to use the streams API.